# Apache Ant setup in Aix

Tags: unix, aix, ant

I want to install Apache Ant on my AIX 6.1 Server and I'm facing some issues.

When I visit the link http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html I did not understand the installation step for the files with the extention .tar.gz

The step is : .tar.gz - Uses the tar program to gather files together, and gzip to compress and uncompress.

Here how do I need to use the tar against the ant .tar.gz binary distribution and how do I use the gzip file.

Answer (score 0):

This means that all of the Ant files and directories are bundled into a .tar file, then that file is compressed into a .gz file.  You can uncompress and unbundle the Ant files and directories using the following commands (first download apache-ant-1.9.1-bin.tar.gz into the directory where you want to install Ant):

> gunzip apache-ant-1.9.1-bin.tar.gz
>   tar -xvf apache-ant-1.9.1-bin.tar

After that you need to continue with the [installation instructions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) that guide you through setting environment variables used by Ant.